# GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT and glMapBufferRange

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Both the OpenGL spec and the OpenGL ES spec don't really say much about `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT`.

They both say something to the effect of

> `MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT` indicates that the GL should not attempt
> to synchronize pending operations on the buffer prior to returning from **Map*BufferRange**. No GL error is generated if pending operations which
> source or modify the buffer overlap the mapped region, but the result of such
> previous and any subsequent operations is undefined.

So, given that definition, is the following code well defined or undefined behavior?

```
// allocate 12 color buffer and copy 12 colors to it
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(twelveColorsAllRed), twelveColorsAllRed, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// map last 6 colors
void* p = glMapBufferRange(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    sizeOf6Colors,  // offset
    sizeOf6Colors,  // size
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT

// update last 6 colors
memcpy(p, sixColorsAllGreen, sizeof(sixColorsAllGreen));

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

// undefined behavior?
glDraw(... arguments and state that use last 6 colors ...)
```

My understanding of the terse spec is this would be undefined behavior. The result could be either green or red or other garbage.

When the actual GPU buffer gets updated is undefined so for example a GL implementation might have queued up some commands to eventually update the GPU buffer with the 12 reds, the map with
`GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT` says "don't worry about synchronizing". The code then copies 6 value to the end of the buffer. At draw time the backend executes it's "update the buffer with 12 reds" and overwrites the results of the map.

Inserting a `glFinish` after the `glBufferData` and before the `glMapBufferRange` would fix it. Also inserting a fence in the same place and waiting on it with `glClientWaitSync` would fix it, but otherwise it's undefined.

Also, in the following example, the 2nd draw is undefined behavior?

```
// allocate 12 color buffer and copy 12 colors to it
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(twelveColorsAllRed), twelveColorsAllRed, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// Safe
glDraw(... arguments and state that use first 6 colors ...)


// map last 6 colors
void* p = glMapBufferRange(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    sizeOf6Colors,  // offset
    sizeOf6Colors,  // size
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT

// update 6 colors
memcpy(p, sixColorsAllGreen, sizeof(sixColorsAllGreen));

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

// Undefined behavior?
glDraw(... arguments and state that use last 6 colors ...)
```

Again, the implementation may have pipelined the steps into

1. queue update of buffer (12 values)
2. queue draw with first 6 values
3. queue draw with last 6 values

So the actual execution would be

1. queue update of buffer (12 values)
2. queue draw with first 6 values
3. map buffer (unsynchronized)
4. update last 6 values
5. unmap
6. queue draw with last 6 values
7. execute queue (update 12 values clobbering step 4, draw, draw)

Again, beacuse the code requested `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT` no synchronization is happening. The point being the first draw doesn't magically guarntee the buffer at map time is synchrnoized. It only guarantees that before the draw happens the buffer will have had those 12 values put into it. Whether the 6 values updated at map time happen before or after that is undefined. Correct?

Note: I want to know for both OpenGL and OpenGL ES. The spec for glMapBufferRange in the OpenGL 4.6 and OpenGL ES 3.0 specs for `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT` have the same wording and AFAICT, for the specific code snippets above should follow the same rules. If OpenGL's specified behavior is different from OpenGL ES's in this area then I'd like to know.

also, to be clear I'm talking about what's allowed by the spec, not what any particular implementation does. It's possible on many implementations the result is deterministic. the question is, does the *spec* specify if the commented draw calls above are defined or undefined behavior.

Comment: So the question is whether unmapping causes synchronization?

Comment: The question is, is the draw with the last 6 values guarnteed to use the green values that were set between map/unmap

Comment: it seems obvious that if unmap synchronizes then yes, if unmap doesn't synchronize then no. Is there any reason you think it might not be one of those?

Comment: Oh you are asking whether the *first* draw is safe, not the last draw?

Comment: I know the first draw is safe in the 2nd example. It's the second draw that's at issue. Unmap has nothing to do with this except as part of the pair of map/unmap. Unmap has no words about sychronization in the spec, only map.

Comment: so if you are asking whether the second draw is safe, that seems the same as asking whether unmap synchronizes. If unmap does not synchronize then why would you expect it to be synchronized?

Comment: No, I am not asking if Unmap is synchronized It's irrelevant if unmap is syncrhonized. I'm asking if the result of the commented draws are defined behavior or undefined behavior. Examples where it would be defined. if `glBufferData` is required to be finished before `glMap` either because `glBufferData` itself effectively does a synchronize or in the 2nd example because the first `glDraw` in the second example effectively does a syncrhronize. If neither of them are guarenteed to syncrhonize updates of the buffer then the map is a race condition. Unmap is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know what your mental model of how map/unmap works but it's allowed to give you a direct pointer to the buffer's memory, for example on unfied memory architectures. That memory might be being written to or scheduled to be written to if you pass in UNSYNCHRONIZE, so you might write green, green, green, ... and the driver over writes that with red, red, red, ....  All that could happen before unmap. Whether unmap synchronizes or not is irrelevant. My reading of the spec is the examples above are undefined behavior. I'm asking for confirmation that my understanding is correct.

Comment: Based on my re-reading of the spec I agree this looks like undefined behavior. If you accept "glBufferData()" can be "an operation" then the map must count as modifying a potentially pending overlapping range.

Comment: @solidpixel: The problem with that logic is that, if you count `glBufferData` as an "operation..." is allocating the data store not *also* part of that "operation"? If so, then it makes absolutely no sense to unsynchronized map without a finish between the allocation and the map call, since the pointer you get may not be pointing into the correct data store.

Comment: That presumes the allocation of the data store and the transfer operation need to be atomic. It almost certainly doesn't need to be - consider the Vulkan equivalent of a memory allocation and the corresponding transfer operation as two disjoint operations.

Comment: It also assumes the mapping is pointing at "the" data store, but again that's really an implementation option which isn't guaranteed. For mapping a non-coherent buffer on a non-unified memory is quite possible that the CPU mapping is actually a staging buffer not the actual buffer the GPU would use, and a driver-managed transfer operation is needed on flush/unmap.

Comment: "it makes no sense to unsynch map without a finish between allocation and map"

Yes, I think that's the implication of the spec wording taken at face value. In reality I think it's very pessimistic on a lot (most?) real implementations - I've never seen anyone actually do it (on mobile at least). Spec wording could probably do with a clarification here.

Comment: @gman: " Unmap has no words about sychronization in the spec, only map." That's beacause that "behave as if it is synchronized" is the default mode for all GL operations, unless explicitly stated otherwise. In my interpretation, it is exactly about what the spec actually writes: whether  you can be sure that writing the data to the buffer will not affect any _previous_ operations using that buffer range (the default, which might have the implementation to block on map, or do some other shadow copy magic), or whether you want to give up that guarantee by the `UNSYNCHRONIZED` bit.

Comment: The spec _never_ talks about the behavior of anything else but the synchornization of the `Map` operation itself for the `UNSYNCHRONIZED` bit. If you assume that the buffer contents are undefined after the unmap of the `UNSYNCHRONIZED` mapped buffer, you would have to assume that it also were undefinied after a unmapping a "normally" mapped buffer - which is of course an absurd idea.

Comment: In my reading of the specs, both of your examples are well-defined, and I can't find any wording in the spec which would hint otherwise. Sourcing data from a buffer after having it unmapped is always well-defined and syncrhronized - this is the whole point of the requirement to not be able to use a buffer while it is mapped in the first place, and you only get unsynchronized access if you map the buffer persistently - which is the much better advice if you plan to manually synchronize the buffer access.

Comment: Also not that while the `MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED` bit does technically avoid a synchronization between the App and the GPU at map time, it still can incur some driver-internal synchronization. This is especially an issue on nvidia's multi-threaded GL implentation and results in a complete performance disaster there - that's also why nvidia recommends to never use unsynchronized mapping in the first place, and to better use a persistent mapping instead.

Comment: @derhass, so it sounds like you're claiming my example of the queue of operations is invalid? My interpretations is the driver can queue up updates to the buffers, under normal circumstances when you called "glMap" it would commit those updates so that what's in the buffer is well defined after calling map. My understanding is UNSYNCHRONIZED is explicitly stating "don't commit the updates", I'll add other synchronization for that. You seem to be suggested that UNSYNCHRONIZED doesn't cause that and is in fact synchronized. If that's the case then UNSYNCHRONIZED has zero point.

Comment: It doesn't have zero point. It tells the driver "you don't have to check wheter there are any pending operations on this buffer (range), I have alreay taken care of that (or I don't care)". `glMapBuffer` doesn't commit anything, but without the unsychronized bit, it _has_ to block to wait for any pervious operations which _may_ write to the buffer to complete, and it has to either block to wait for any pending operatons which _may_ read from the buffer, or do some shenaningans so that you writing to the buffer doesn't affect pending operations reading from it.

Comment: It has no effect on anything which happens _after_ the driver returned from the map operation , as this is literally what the spec says, and it has no effect on anything on the examples you stated because the "`MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT` indicates that the GL should not attempt to synchronize pending operations on the buffer prior to returning from `Map*BufferRange`." premise is not fulfilled at all - there are no pending operations prior to the map operation which overlap witth the buffer range you are mapping, so the effect of this code with this flag has to be the same as without it.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. I gave an example of pending operations. I know several drivers that have these pending operations.  AFAICT the spec allows them to have these pending operations and that passing UNSYNCHRONIZED will mean you get undefined behavior since you just told the drive "don't worry if you have pending operations". So the only real questions are what pending operations are allowed. It says right in definition there can be pending operations. So the question then becomes, do the commands before map in the examples above have possible pending operations.

Comment: I also gave examples of how those pending operations lead to UB. You can't know if you'll end up with red or green in the buffer since you don't know if these pending operations will happen before or after you write to the buffer after calling glMap. If they happen before you'll get green, if they happen after you'll get red, if they happen on another thread and both threads are writing at the same time you might get yellow etc.... undefined.

Comment: "I also gave examples of how those pending operations lead to UB." Where? Your examples all map the _second_ half of your buffer, and never use the _first_ half of the buffer prior to the map (or after, but that is irrelevant). There are no pending operations which source or write to the second half of the buffer. The `glBufferData` has to be synchronized with the map in any case, as it actually _creates_ the buffer storage it is about to map, The spec clarifies that it addrsses pending operations "which source or **modify**" the buffer range, not which **create** it.

Comment: All of the examples write 12 red values (the entire buffer) in the first call `glBufferData` and then write 6 green values to the last 6 values in the buffer `glMap/copy/glUnmap`  The 12 red values may be pending. If they are, they'll happen after writing the 6 green values.

Comment: It is in reality very simple: `glBufferDatat(12 colors);glDraw(the first six colors);glMap(the first six colors)` is fine without the `MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED`, and UB with it. And nothing else is changes by the bit.

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood. I thought were were staying above there is no UB. Now you're saying there is. If so, we agree, there is UB.

Comment: `glBufferData` is **not** modifying (nor sourcing) the contents of any buffer objects. It creates (and optionally initializes) a new buffer storage, It is not referenced by the language used to describe the `MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED` at all. It would also be completely usless in the real world if it were otherwise.

Comment: no, we don't agree. I'm talking abut a different example where the values you may overwrite after the map are actually used before the map, in the way as mentioned but the  spec - sourced or modified, in this case, sourced by a draw call.

Comment: Still not sure what you think you're saying. MAP_UNSYCHRONIZED doesn't have to reference anything. All it has to say is "pending operations". Nearly everything in GL can be a pending operation. I'm saying I believe `glBufferData` (where I passed 12 reds) can be a pending operation (I know drivers where it is). `glMap(UNSYNCED)` says "ignore the pending operations" so whether those 12 reds get written before or after the 6 greens is undefined. They overlap, (reread the code).  If every step was sync then 12 reds would get written, RRRRRRRRRRRR, then 6 greens so RRRRRRGGGGGG.

Comment: With unsynced you  have ???????????? (the allocation) then ??????GGGGGG then RRRRRRRRRRRR, or, ???????????? -> RRRRRRRRRRRR -> RRRRRRGGGGGG. You could even end up with RRRRRRGRRGRG hence it's undefined what the last 6 values will be.

Comment: And this is where we disagree. The spec talks about pending operations which _source or modify_ the buffer contents here. I'm saying that `glBufferData` doesn't source (obvoiously) nor modify the buffer contents. And I say it doesn't _modify_ any previous buffer contents, because either is no data stoarge (which means it couldn't be mapped at all) before that, or it is discarding the previous data storage by a new one, initalized by the values you give.

Comment: But I agree that `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED` bit is completely useless - either you made some explicit synchronization to make sure that no operations on the buffer range are in flight, you just don't use the bit and get the same synchronization just implicitly. There are only two scenarios where it can gain performance; you explicitly go for the UB and don't care about it, or you absultely know better than the driver that the buffer range you map is not sourced or modified by operations still in flight (because for example you have some complex shader logic which will only access parts)

Comment: glBufferData does modify the buffer, it's equivalent to allocate + glBufferSubData, in fact I know drivers that are implemented this way, they do the allocation and then just chain to their implementation of glBufferSubData. clearly allocation is a separate operation from filling it with memory. Even in just plain C one operation is malloc, the second is memcpy. glBufferSubData is defined as modifying the buffer so glBufferData is also modifying the (just allocated) buffer.

Comment: Now you might disagree with my interpretation of the spec - and I can't blame you for that. There is some room for interpretation here, and that is also why I didn't write this as an answer. I'd just commented on how I read this. The thing we seem to disagree here is whetehr `glBufferData` counts as _modifying_ the buffer contents. Which I say it doesnt - as asumming the opposite would imply aburd behavior in my book - mapping a buffer storage before it even exists, which would mean the result of the map operation _itself_ would be UB, not just of the pending ops - not what the spec says.

Comment: I'd say it does because if you call gLBufferData with null you get an buffer with random contents. In order to make it non-random that buffer needs to be modified with data

Comment: That's not what the spec says. It doesn't say its equivalent to a `glBufferData(...,NULL); glSubBufferData`. It says `glBufferData` and `glBufferStorage` _create_ the data storage, and `glBufferSubData`  _modifies_ the data storage. That some implementations implement it as a series of these two steps doesn't mean they don't put the proper synchronization primitives in where needed.

Comment: In my experience - and this is **not** backed up by the spec (as far as I'm aware) - the actual point about these in-flight operations is server side operations reading or writing to the buffer (i.e. directly by the GPU). The GL implementation having _client side_ operations in flight is not what I think the authors of the `GL_ARB_map_buffer_range` extension (which introduces this flag) had in mind. And this is also why `MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED` is such a client-side _synchronization_ hell. But again, this is nothing I can back up by any section of the spec directly.

Comment: I think your example of splitting `glBufferData` into a separate "allocate" and "modify: step is misleading. It is obvoius that the `glMapBuffer` in _any_ case has to take the latest "allocate" step into account - as this is defining the size of the buffer storage at all, so it _always_ has to syncrhonize to that point, otherwise your own examples wouldn't have the UB at the draw call after the unmap, but at the map calli tself, and any writing of data during the map could lead to a anythingf. Now if we have the map operation synchronizing on the allocate, why not on the initialization, too?

Comment: Let's imagine I decide to implement putting data in a buffer via gl commands (vs mapping) as always (copy the data somewhere, queue a copy of that data to the actual buffer on the GPU, execute that queue before the data is needed for drawing). Without GL map this will always lead to valid behavior. glBufferSubData will do these operations. glBufferData will first allocate the buffer, then just call glBufferSubData. Everything works. It's spec compliant. Along comes glMap/glUnmap. This also works as long as glMap executes this queue of pending operations. There's no absurd behavior whatsoever

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that implementation, using staging buffers in a queue to get data into a the actual buffers is invalid. It will pass every GL test ever made that doesn't use glMap(unsynced). The splitting of "allocation" vs "modifying" is totally natural, why implement something twice when it can be implemented once. Nothing says everything has to be queued (allocations do not have to be queued just because modifications are). An example of this stuff are Vulkan/Metal/DX12 where you have queues of operations. Getting data into a buffer can often be faster by queuing an operation.

Comment: The reason I asked for clarification is mostly to make sure such an implementation is valid by the spec. AFAICT it is. If an implementation queues all version of "put user data in buffer" (that is both glBufferData and glBufferSubData), then the examples in the question are undefined behavior. If on the other hand such an implementation is doing something against the spec, then I'd like to know that.

Comment: There is no way a valid implementation (using staging buffers or not) can return from the `glBufferData` call before it has taken the user data to some place. So the client side order is defined in any case. Now you claim that this could lead to a pending buffer modification server-side, while the spec never says that this operation is a modification in the first place.

Comment: I never say that implementations using staging buffers are invalid, or that you can't internally do a separate allocate and modify step - just that if you do, you have to take care at the map operation that some of this might be in flight, and have to sync (or directly give a pointer to the staging buffer is the transfer hasn't started, or whatever) if that might be the case. What I'm saying is that conceptually, we absolutely need `allocate; fence; ...; map(Unsync) -> wait for fence`, and we  can put the fence after the iniial copy as well, nothing implemeted twice here, no perf penalty.

Comment: I think where we disagree is the actual meaning of "unynchronized" here. You seem to imply that it means "give me some pointer instantly no matter what", while I think it means "give me some pointer, you don't have to sync to _certain_ pending operations".  Your interpretation would mean that `BufferData(NULL);Map(Unsyc)` already has to be UB without an explicit sync inbetween, because the allocation might not have happened at all yet, and the map can't give you a valid pointer.

Comment: My interpretation leads to this being well-defined, and I go further as to imply that the implicit sync requirement  not only refers to the allocate step, but to the whole create step, which can include the initial copy of the data. My interpretation is based on the wording of the _creation_ vs. _modification_ as used in the spec, but I do agree that it is not exactly clear if this is the intention of the authors of the spec, and a clarification on the issue would be needed.

Comment: For all practical purposes, your view is more general. It just requires you to put an explicit sync between the `BufferData` and the `Map(Unsync)`. If you're right, then it is necessary to avoid UB in your examples, and if I'm right, then it is just redundant (but should not cost much). The actual point of the unsychronized map - bypassing syncs on in-flight server side operations where the client only sees the bound buffer (range), but not the range of the actually accessed parts - are not affected by any of these views.